# Manage (min max restore) other windows in node webkit (or in node.js or cmd) - task bar alternative

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, batch-file, node-webkit

I am creating custom UI for windows (windows shell replacement), where themes are created using css (and app is created in javascript and html + nwjs - nodewebkit)
The problem is I don't know how to make task bar - how to manage (min max restore) other windows (non nodewebkit like chrome, ixplorer, firefox, winamp...).
Is there a easy way to make it in javascript or batch (cmd or bat file) or maybe nodejs package.

Or I need to learn coding in c or c++ to make something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corey Butler's [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) is the closest thing that I'm aware of.  If it were me, and I were determined *not* to write this using Microsoft Visual Studio in C++ or C#, I think my approach would be to grab the full set of node-windows code and node_modules and then go to school on the underlying set of code.  Somewhere within those dependencies someone has exposed part of the WIN32 API for iterating and controlling/installing NT services.  In theory, one could fetch *that* module and work up a new one to provide access to the familiar methods to iterate and control windows by their handles.

Comment: I suppose a full answer would open up the issue of "native" versus "non-native" code.  Most native modules are not distributed in binary form and require the end-user to build them using node-gyp.  You, the end-user, would need a full install of Visual Studio in other words.  Alternately, a non-native module would not need Visual Studio and would already have a compiled binary.  What this means to you is that if you have VS you could take either approach.  If you wanted to have others use your new module this is something to think about.

Comment: thanks for tips, i have no clue about c++ or c# so for now i will use windows taskbar and later try something easier like autohotkey script or something similar

Comment: I considered writing a Windows program maybe three months ago.  I was annoyed about non-minimized windows getting in the way and wanted to create a program which would listen to a hotkey and then minimize all windows.  Even in MSVC this isn't necessarily an easy task.

Comment: I was looking for similar program two mouths ago. I found autohotkey is super and very flexible program. There is a windows shortcut key for minimizing all windows (not winkey+m and winkey+shift+m) winkey+d but with autohotkey i binded it for one key (Numpad+). And now i found this page http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/8227-can-ahk-open-those-windows-minimized-in-sys-tray/  I think i can try to do this by pid or class name ... https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMaximize.htm

Comment: I think this is easiest method for my skills :-( (if it works)

Comment: @genesix.eu Hey, thanks for the Win+D combo, btw.  ;)